# How to switch off garbage collection in Xcode 4.5, and get rid of clang error 1 when switching on ARC?

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

I just reopened a project that was set to use Garbage Collection, and that I had last opened in Xcode 3. Now opening it again in Xcode 4.5, and looking to modernize it, I am trying to switch on ARC. However, when building, it resulted in clang error 1. Looking into more details in the Xcode logs, I saw the message:

clang: error: cannot specify both '-fobjc-arc' and '-fobjc-gc-only'

Ah, I need to switch off Garbage Collection, which I was using before. However, when searching the build setting for the word 'garbage' or 'collection', I can't find the setting in Xcode (using the search field in the Build Settings in the target info).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably because garbage collection is now deprecated, the setting has been turned into a user-defined setting, and is using the gcc name 'GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC'. This is why it won't show up when doing a search for 'garbage' or 'collection'. Instead, you have to look for that setting at the bottom of the Build Settings, or search for the string GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC using the search field.

This needs to be done at the project level or at the target level.

Comment: Target level setting override project level settings; so you shouldn't have to do it at both. Ether set it at the Project level for all targets or on specific targets if they're they only ones that need it specified.